# Natural rotation with Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to move my robot foot correctly, but I can't get the top part (blue part) to rotate as it was attached to the leg (green part).

How can I do this?

[image]

When I activate the node it rotates, but not in a good way

[image]

My principal Node

[image]

My Leg node

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's the good way to do it, but it works.

[image]

My new Geometry Nodes

[image]

And the Blend File

[image]